# Do you get your Hunters Axe back?

Tags: xcom-2

In the new XCOM 2 DLC one of the new weapons is a Hunters Axe, one option allows you to throw one of the axes at an enemy.  If you do this, do you get the axe back or is it lost forever?   When I first got it the message said it was one of a kind and could not be built again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get the axe back.

As long as the soldier who wields the axes is not left behind on a mission (dies, is captured, doesn't make the evac in time), you will keep both axes after the mission.

Answer (score 1):

You get the axe back IF the unit equipped with it survives the mission and returns safely with the squad. This said, you cannot go and retrieve the second axe from a corpse. It is a one-time use per mission, but as the axes come in pairs, you can still use your melee even after having thrown one, and you will regain the throwing axe next mission.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a mod now for WOTC that lets you recover the axe 1 turn after you threw it at someone (the 1 turn cooldown is to prevent abuse). Really nice and realistic.

https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1215333362